# A good way to use sed to find and replace characters with 2 delimiters

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I  trying to find and replace items using bash. I was able to use `sed` to grab out some of the characters, but I think I might be using it in the wrong matter.

I am basically trying to remove the characters after ";" and before "," including removing ","

```
sed -e 's/\(;\).*\(,\)/\1\2/'
```

That is what I used to replace it with nothing. However, it ends up replacing everything in the middle so my output came out like this:

```
cmd2="BMC,./socflash_x64 if=B600G3_BMC_V0207.ima;,reboot -f"
```

---

This is the original text of what I need to replace

```
cmd2="BMC,./socflash_x64 if=B600G3_BMC_V0207.ima;X,sleep 120;after_BMC,./run-after-bmc-update.sh;hba_fw,./hba_fw.sh;X,sleep 5;DB,2;X,reboot -f"
```

---

Is there any way to make it look like this output?

```
./socflash_x64 if=B600G3_BMC_V0207.ima;sleep 120;./run-after-bmc-update.sh;./hba_fw.sh;sleep 5;reboot -f
```

Ff there is any way to make this happen other than bash I am fine with any type of language.

Comment: The problem is that sed uses greedy search, you need something like perl that has non greedy regex matching.

Answer (score 3):

Non-greedy search can (mostly) be simulated in programs that don't support it by replacing match-any (dot `.`) with a negated character class.

Your original command is

```
sed -e 's/\(;\).*\(,\)/\1\2/'
```

You want to match everything in between the semi-colon and the comma, but not another comma (non-greedy). Replace `.*` with `[^,]*`

```
sed -e 's/\(;\)[^,]*\(,\)/\1\2/'
```

You *may* also want to exclude semi-colons themselves, making the expression

```
sed -e 's/\(;\)[^,;]*\(,\)/\1\2/'
```

Note this would treat a string like "asdf;zxcv;1234,qwer" differently, since one would match `;zxcv;1234,` and the other would match only `;1234,`

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
echo $cmd2 | tr ';' '\n' | cut -d',' -f2- | tr '\n' ';' ; echo
```

result is:

```
./socflash_x64 if=B600G3_BMC_V0207.ima;sleep 120;./run-after-bmc-update.sh;./hba_fw.sh;sleep 5;2;reboot -f;
```

however, I thing your requirements are a few more complex, because 'DB,2' seems a particular case. After "tr" command, insert a "grep" or "grep -v" to include/exclude these cases.

Answer (score 1):

In perl:

```
perl -pe 's/;.*?,/;/g;' -pe 's/^[^,]*,//' foo.txt
```

will output:

```
./socflash_x64 if=B600G3_BMC_V0207.ima;sleep 120;./run-after-bmc-update.sh;./hba_fw.sh;sleep 5;2;reboot -f
```

The .*? is non greedy matching before the comma. The second command is to remove from the beginning to the comma.